# Ping.SendAsync() returned replay from 0.0.0.0, how to get pinged address?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, asynchronous, ping

i have problem with Ping.SendAsync() function in C#.
I ping some ip adresses, but some of they are wrong. I need to remove wrong adresses from list. But how, because p_PingCompleted *event args.replay.adress* is *0.0.0.0*?
Here is my code:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<Game> GameList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Game>();
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);

        public StartServer()
        {
            this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8888);
            this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
            this.listenThread.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Master server running...");
            timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            timer.Start();
        }

        void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Game[] games = GameList.ToArray();
            foreach (Game curgame in games)
            {
                System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping p = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
                p.PingCompleted += new System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingCompletedEventHandler(p_PingCompleted);
                p.SendAsync(IPAddress.Parse(curgame.IP), new object());
            }
            SendMessageToAll(output);
            Console.WriteLine("Timer.Elapsed with data [" + output + "]");
        }

        void p_PingCompleted(object sender, System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ping reply from: " + e.Reply.Address.ToString() + " has " + e.Reply.RoundtripTime.ToString() + " ms.");
            if (e.Reply.RoundtripTime == 0 ||
                e.Reply.RoundtripTime >= 2500)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("   Removing this server because ping is 0 or is greater than 2500 ms");
            }
        }
```

And output is:

> ```
> Pinging 16.5.4.3...
> Ping reply from: 0.0.0.0 has 0 ms.
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`UserState` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.userstate.aspx) and a lock to ensure serialized access to `GameList`:

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (new string('a', 32));
var options = new PingOptions (32, true);

Ping p = new Ping();
p.PingCompleted += p_PingCompleted;
foreach (Game curgame in GameList.ToArray())
{
    // e.UserState will be curgame
    p.SendAsync(IPAddress.Parse(curgame.IP), 2500, buffer, options, curgame);
}
```

Then in your `p_PingCompleted` handler:

```
void p_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var game = (Game)e.UserState;
    if (e.Reply.Status != IPStatus.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "  Could not reach {0} ({1}), removing this server...",
            game.IP,
            e.Reply.Status);
        lock (GameList)
        {
            GameList.Remove(game);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Ping reply from: {0} in {1} ms",
            e.Reply.Address,
            e.Reply.RoundtripTime);
        if (e.Reply.RoundtripTime == 0 ||
            e.Reply.RoundtripTime >= 2500)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  Ping too high, removing this server...");
            lock (GameList)
            {
                GameList.Remove(game);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good but it does not explain why he is getting 0.0.0.0 for the IP.

Comment: @0A0D: I'll bet in those cases `PingReply.Status` is something like destination unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

In the async call, send the Ping object (or game object, whatever list you're dealing with) as the object state, and then from the ping completed event, just remove that object from the list if the address is invalid.

Comment: You mean `p.SendAsync(IPAddress.Parse(curgame.IP), curgame);` ?

Comment: Yes. and just use in the ping completed code, `GamesList.Remove(e.UserState);`

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do how you are using `SendAsync(string, object)`.

At [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx), it has a pretty good example. Use `SendAsync(String, Int32, Byte[], PingOptions, Object)` or `SendAsync(IPAddress, Int32, Byte[], PingOptions, Object)` instead. Follow that example and it should work for you.