# Retrieving ping host name from SendPingAsync result

Tags: c#, dns, ping

I'm pinging hosts from list of strings (addresses). Everything works perfectly but when host is unreachable ping returns `Result.Address`: "0.0.0.0" instead of existing address or hostname which I passed into SendPingAsync function.
Here is my code:

```
            var pingTasks = addresses.Select(address =>
            {
                return new Ping().SendPingAsync(address);
            });

            await Task.WhenAll(pingTasks);

            StringBuilder pingResultBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var pingReply in pingTasks)
            {
                pingResultBuilder.Append(pingReply.Result.Address);
                pingResultBuilder.Append("    ");

                pingResultBuilder.Append(pingReply.Result.Status);
                pingResultBuilder.Append("    ");

                pingResultBuilder.Append(pingReply.Result.RoundtripTime.ToString());
                pingResultBuilder.AppendLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine(pingResultBuilder.ToString());
```

I found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602845/ping-sendasync-returned-replay-from-0-0-0-0-how-to-get-pinged-address) but I need to do the same thing in `SendPingAsync` function instead of `SendAsync`.
How can I retrieve passed `host name / ip address` from `pingReply.Result`?

Comment: you'd have to do a DNS lookup on something that isn't responding.

Comment: My app must be performance oriented and I would like to not include any unnecessary operations. Unless I need to do this, but if there's a way to retrieve this IP I would like to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write an extension method using `SendAsync`.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static Task<PingResult> SendTaskAsync(this Ping ping, string address)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<PingResult>();
        PingCompletedEventHandler response = null;
        response = (s, e) =>
        {
            ping.PingCompleted -= response;
            tcs.SetResult(new PingResult() { Address = address, Reply = e.Reply });
        };
        ping.PingCompleted += response;
        ping.SendAsync(address, address);
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public class PingResult
    {
        public string Address { set; get; }
        public PingReply Reply { set; get; }
    }
}
```

You can now use it like:

```
var pingTasks = addresses.Select(address =>
{
    return new Ping().SendTaskAsync(address);
});

var replies = await Task.WhenAll(pingTasks);

StringBuilder pingResultBuilder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var pingReply in replies)
{
    pingResultBuilder.Append(pingReply.Address);
    pingResultBuilder.Append("    ");

    pingResultBuilder.Append(pingReply.Reply.Status);
    pingResultBuilder.Append("    ");

    pingResultBuilder.Append(pingReply.Reply.RoundtripTime.ToString());
    pingResultBuilder.AppendLine();
}

Console.WriteLine(pingResultBuilder.ToString());
```

Comment: @TMcKeown By returning the address of the site that is pinged :) See the line `pingResultBuilder.Append(pingReply.Address);`

Comment: I see, I thought the problem was that there was no data, I misread.... nice solution.

Comment: I know this is somewhat old. But with your extension I now get the error on the foreach:
    Error 1 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<namespace.MyExtensions.PingResult[]>' because 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<NightWatchmanAsyncReport.MyPingExtensions.PingResult[]>' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I tried to implement such GetEnumerator but failed.